# iOS Swift navigation title is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBarController under which I loaded some navigation controller. But the title of my navigation controller is not showing up. Even I noticed if I add buttons in my left and right navbar item, it doesn't show up as well.

**My Tabbar Setup:**

```swift
let quranNavigationController = UINavigationController()

//        quranNavigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
//        quranNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = Colors.primaryTextColor
//        quranNavigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = Colors.navigationBackgroundPrimary

let quranSnackBarController = AppSnackbarController(rootViewController: quranNavigationController)
quranSnackBarController.shouldExtend = false
quranSnackBarController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Books".localized(), image: UIImage(named: "quran"), tag: 1);

let menuViewController = TestViewController()
let quranController = QuranPrintController()
let sideMenuController = SideMenuController(contentViewController: quranController, menuViewController: menuViewController)
quranNavigationController.viewControllers = [sideMenuController]

tabBarController.viewControllers = [homeNavigationController2, quranSnackBarController, prayerNavigationController, duaSnackBarController]
window.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

QuranPrintController:

```
class QuranPrintController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Quran"
        self.navigationItem.title = "Prayer Times"
    }

}
```

This is what my output is. No title is shown. I tried adding buttons on the left and right sides. But didn't work as well

[image: Output]

Comment: How did you setup rootViewController?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your tabbarcontroller is embedded with navigation controller and then your all controllers are connected with your navbar

like this

[image]

then embed your navigation controllers with your each view controller with seperate navigController

Answer (score -1):

Try Add this in your ViewdidLoad() .

```
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourbuttonname)
```